# Firebase Database - Strange error when creating and removing nodes (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two Firebase queries, one for adding an ID to a node (named blocklist) and one for deleting an ID from the same node.

They are each triggered by one of two buttons: a "Block" button and an "Unblock" button.

These are the functions:

```
function blockUser(){

        // friendToBlock is the ID I want to add to the block list:
        var friendToBlock = document.getElementById('hiddenUid').innerHTML;

        // globaluid is the currently logged in user's ID:
        firebase.database().ref('users/'+globaluid+'/blocklist/').push({
            blockedId:friendToBlock
        });

        console.log(friendToBlock+" is now blocked!");          
}


function unblockUser(){

        // friendToUnblock is the ID I want to remove from the block list:
        var friendToUnblock = document.getElementById('hiddenUid').innerHTML;

        var blockedRef = firebase.database().ref('users/'+globaluid+'/blocklist/');
        var blockedQuery = blockedRef.orderByChild('blockedId').equalTo(friendToUnblock);
            blockedQuery.on('child_added', function(blockedSnapshot) {
                blockedSnapshot.ref.remove(function (error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        console.log(friendToUnblock+" should now be unblocked.");
                        }
            });
    });             
}
```

These two functions are working perfectly the first time I run the app, however if I click "Block", "Unblock" and then "Block" again, the second Block event triggers both functions for some reason.

I have the Firebase console open and can see the `blocklist` node being created and then immediately being deleted half a second later, which means that the "Block" button is triggering both functions.

For some reason this doesn't happen the first time I press the buttons after opening the app, it only occurs when pressing the "Block" button after pressing the "Unblock" button.

I can't figure out what could be wrong with my code, I am wondering does Firebase have a limit on how fast you can create a node after deleting an identically-named node in the database?

I'd really appreciate any help or advice on this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After working on this a bit longer I've been able to fix it.

I think the problem was being caused by the line:

```
blockedQuery.on('child_added', function(blockedSnapshot) ...
```

It seems that this continued to listen and get triggered whenever the blocklist node was recreated by `blockUser();`.

I changed it to:

```
blockedQuery.once('value', function(blockedSnapshot) ...
```

And now it's adding and removing the `blocklist` node correctly with no errors.